# Wondering whether my perception is correct on this short text

Tags: sentence-meaning

"We are working in a very big ocean and within a very large search area, and so far since the aircraft went missing we have had **very few** leads **which allow us to narrow** the search area," he said.

http://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-26908884

Which of the following perception of mine is correct?

1. We have had very few leads so far and therefore it is difficult for us to narrow the search area.
2. We have had very few leads so far and that has allowed us to narrow the search area.

Comment: Not quite. Replace "which" by "that" and I believe that it'll be easier for you to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is signalled by the absence of a comma, the relative clause *which allow us to narrow the search area* is a restrictive clause modifying the NP *very few leads*. The speaker is only talking about leads of the sort which allow us to narrow the search area, not about other leads.

Presumably, however, each of these leads only allowed us to narrow the search area by a small amount. Since there are only a few of them, we have only been able to narrow the search area a little bit, so it is still very large—216,000 km<sup>2</sup>. That’s a circle with a radius of more than 250 km.

Comment: Hmm. What if it said, "We have had very few leads which (or that) have allowed us to narrow the search area"? The quote in the OP is a bit wonky in comparison, but is the meaning really different?. I'm actually leaning towards Damkerng's comment as a preferred answer.

Comment: @Jolenealaska Which and that are both acceptable in restrictive clauses, so Yes, the meaning is the same: "leads of the sort which have allowed us to narrow the search area".

Comment: So there have have been very few leads to narrow the search area? Yes? That seems to conflict with "each of these leads has allowed us to narrow the search area".

Comment: So we assume that of the few leads we are talking about, they all narrow the search area? Other leads aren't a part of this sentence?

Comment: @Jolene The search area has been narrowed, but only by a little because there have been so few leads. It still covers over 200,000 square km.

Comment: @Jolenealaska Exactly. He's only talking about "leads which allow &c" - "which allow &c" is a restrictive clause modifying "leads" ... lemme edit.

Comment: One more question, if you don't mind. Imagine the statement, "Very little has changed to convince me to trust you." Does that really imply that there has been any increase in trust? Or even that there have even been any changes to engender such trust? If that statement is different, how?

Comment: @Jolenealaska I'd say this is structurally pretty much the same, but there is this difference: a search area is "scalar", but trust is pretty much binary, either you trust somebody or you don't. Your sentence in effect says "There have been small changes, but not been enough to make me trust you any more", where OP's sentence says "The leads have made our job easiER, but not easy."